# Compare tree data in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have two tree structures one is source tree that contains all leafs, other one CALLED `selected`, this is just a copy of source tree and missing some leafs, I need to compare source tree and `selected` and get output same as source but just update the leafs with comparing it with `selected`.
Like any source leaf contains same children then I the want to update source leaf with `state: full`. If no children is selected state is `state: no`, if some children is selected `state: partial`.

I have try to flat the selected tree into array of ids, so i can match the selected  ones with `source`, but I'm stuck in the logic of updating the output tree. please check my expected output.

```js
const recursCollectIds = ({tree}) => {
 return (tree || [])
   .map(leaf => { return  (leaf.children && leaf.children.length) ? [leaf.id].concat(recursCollectIds({tree: leaf.children})) : [leaf.id] } )
    .flatMap(x => x)
}

const selected = [{
        id: 4,
        name: 'F',
        children: [{
            id: 8,
            name: 'V',
            children: []
        }, {
            id: 9,
            name: 'T',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'B',
        children: [{
            id: 17,
            name: 'R',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'O',
        children: [{
            id: 90,
            name: 'Y',
            children: [{
                id: 37,
                name: 'FU',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }
]

const source = [{
        id: 4,
        name: 'F',
        children: [{
            id: 8,
            name: 'V',
            children: [{
                id: 3,
                name: 'F',
                children: []
            }]
        }, {
            id: 9,
            name: 'T',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'B',
        children: [{
            id: 17,
            name: 'R',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'O',
        children: [{
            id: 90,
            name: 'Y',
            children: [{
                id: 37,
                name: 'FU',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }
]


const updateTree = ({source, selected}) => {
  const selectedIds = recursCollectIds({tree: selected})
  // need to check with ids of selected and source tree 
  
}

updateTree({source, selected})
```

Expected output

```
    const out = [{
        state: 'partial', // due to its children or grand children is selected partially
        id: 4,
        name: 'F',
        children: [{
            state: 'partial', // due to its children or grand children is selected partially
            id: 8,
            name: 'V',
            children: [{
                state: 'no', // due to non of its children selected
                id: 3,
                name: 'F',
                children: []
            }]
        }, {
            state: 'full', // no children so no need to match. 
            id: 9,
            name: 'T',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        state: 'full',
        id: 5,
        name: 'B',
        children: [{
            state: 'full',
            id: 17,
            name: 'R',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        state: 'full',
        id: 7,
        name: 'O',
        children: [{
            state: 'full',
            id: 90,
            name: 'Y',
            children: [{
                state: 'full',
                id: 37,
                name: 'FU',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isUndefined = val => ((typeof val == "undefined") && (val == null));

const isArray = val => ((!isUndefined(val)) && (Array.isArray(val)));

const modifyObject = tree => {
    let respObject = {};
    (isArray(tree) ? tree : []).forEach(leaf => {
        respObject[leaf.id] = leaf;
        if(!isUndefined(leaf.children) && (leaf.children.length > 0)) {
            respObject[leaf.id]["children"] = modifyObject(leaf.children)
        }
    });
    return respObject;
}

const constructResp = (source,selected) => {
    return (isArray(source) ? source : []).map(currentElem=>{
        let currSourceChild = currentElem.children;
        currSourceChild = isUndefined(currSourceChild) ? [] : currSourceChild;
        let currElemSelectedChild = selected[currentElem.id];
        if(isUndefined(currElemSelectedChild)){
            currentElem['state'] = 'no';
            return currentElem;
        } else if(currSourceChild.length == 0){
            currentElem['state'] = 'full';
            return currentElem;
        } else{
            let currSourceUpdatedChild = constructResp(currSourceChild,currElemSelectedChild.children);
            let currIndex = 0;
            let childLen = currSourceUpdatedChild.length;
            for(;currIndex<childLen;currIndex++){
                if(currSourceUpdatedChild[currIndex].state != 'full'){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(currIndex == childLen){
                currentElem['state'] = 'full';
            } else {
                currentElem['state'] = 'partial';
            }
            return currentElem;
        }
    })
}

const selected = [{
        id: 4,
        name: 'F',
        children: [{
            id: 8,
            name: 'V',
            children: []
        }, {
            id: 9,
            name: 'T',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'B',
        children: [{
            id: 17,
            name: 'R',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'O',
        children: [{
            id: 90,
            name: 'Y',
            children: [{
                id: 37,
                name: 'FU',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }
]

const source = [{
        id: 4,
        name: 'F',
        children: [{
            id: 8,
            name: 'V',
            children: [{
                id: 3,
                name: 'F',
                children: []
            }]
        }, {
            id: 9,
            name: 'T',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'B',
        children: [{
            id: 17,
            name: 'R',
            children: []
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'O',
        children: [{
            id: 90,
            name: 'Y',
            children: [{
                id: 37,
                name: 'FU',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }
]


const updateTree = ({source, selected}) => {
  let modifiedSelected = modifyObject(selected)
  let finalResp = constructResp(source,modifiedSelected);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResp,null,4));
}

updateTree({source, selected})
```